# SUM UP Min Measure DAX Power BI

Tags: performance, powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I have this data table. I want to return MIN of Lost Sales, SOH and SIT

- If the earliest StockAvailDate is before end of current month => incluce SIT
- If the earliest StockAvailDate is after end of current month => excluce SIT

[image]

My measure:
Recover =
VAR SI_date = CALCULATE( sum ('Fact - SIT'[SIT Qty]), filter ( all ('Fact - SIT'[StockAvailDate]), 'Fact - SIT'[StockAvailDate] < EOMONTH( today () ,0 )))

VAR DCSOH =
IF (
CALCULATE ( SUM ( 'Fact - 5810 SOH'[DC Stock] ) ) = BLANK (),
0,
CALCULATE ( SUM ( 'Fact - 5810 SOH'[DC Stock]) )
)
VAR temp = { [Lost Sales Qty (Net)], DCSOH, SI_date }
RETURN
MINX ( Temp, [Value] )

Here is Measure return:
[image]

My question:

1. Why first 2 lines return to 0? I want it return to 30 & 15 as SIT colum = 1410 and available date is still less than 30 Nov
2. Sum colum Qty SI return to the min of 3 colums. How can i sum those based on the Qty SI colum.

Thank you.

Out come i would like to achive:

[image]